# Scrapy crawler gives DNS lookup error while increasing the concurrency of spider

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have written a crawler, which works perfectly fine if i use default setting of scrapy. I have already tested it with 10K URLs but I have millions of URLs to **scrape** and I also want that to be fast, so I have changed the default CONCURRENT_REQUESTS to 300. All works fine for first few 100 URLs(it contain above tested 10K URLs) but then all of a sudden rest of the URLs started giving DNS lookup error.
I am not sure what causing this issue, URL seems to find and it worked with default setting.

My crawler runs on windows 10 machine which has 2 core and 4 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Setup your own DNS](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/broad-crawls.html#setup-your-own-dns) section of the [Broad Crawls](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/broad-crawls.html) page of the Scrapy documentation.